# Can I use asynchronous timer in PHP and how to do it?

Tags: php

I have an app with PHP(on websockets) and I need to create a few timers lasting three seconds each. When time is up in the timers, I change bool variable. Each timer changes its own variable. I can't use sleep because my program must be active.

I thought the timer in react php would be asynchronous, but it behaves just like sleep().  Here's my code:

```
    $loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $timer = $loop->addTimer(3, function() {
        // some acts
    });

    $loop->run();
```

How can I make an asynchronous timer?

Comment: why don't you use a cronjob for each timer?

Comment: @Victor Radu I don't know cron yet. This task may be solved using cron?

Comment: The `cron` service doesn't help here. It is used to run commands on the system at some moments in time (with 1 minute resolution).

Comment: @axiac Thanks for explanation. Then I will learn background workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use background workers. [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) is great for these things.

Comment: @Ramy Talal - I like the idea, but I dont believe Gearman supports delayed jobs. So the background worker would still need to sleep for 3 seconds, and therefore, the php consumer would still be **blocking**. As such, right idea, wrong tool?

Comment: @Gravy In a way it's possible to delay a job: https://medium.com/@abbiya/yo-yo-yo-include-gearman-and-redis-in-your-php-app-1d9a9e0b40ac#.78cloax7m But Beanstalkd would indeed be better.

Comment: @RamyTalal - In that case, you may as well just use Redis as your messaging queue. No need for added Gearman complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I like Ramy Talal's recommendation to use a queueing server like Gearman, however I don't believe Gearman supports delayed jobs - there is no mention of it in the gearman protocol either http://gearman.org/protocol/. I would go with something like Beanstalkd.

http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/

You have one PHP process responsible for putting a job on a queue with a delay, and a second php process for consuming from the queue.

A nice library client for beanstalk is pheanstalk. https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk which you can install via composer.

Simple usage example:

Producer

```
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');

$delay = 3; // delay in seconds
$pheanstalk
  ->useTube('choose_tube_name')
  ->put("job payload goes here\n",
      PheanstalkInterface::DEFAULT_PRIORITY, // 1024 as standard
      $delay,
      PheanstalkInterface::DEFAULT_TTR // I think that after 60 seconds by default, if not deleted by consumer after reserving job, it is automatically released back onto the queue to be consumed by another consumer.
);
```

Consumer

```
while (1) {
    $job = $pheanstalk
      ->watch('choose_tube_name')
      ->ignore('default')
      ->reserve();

    echo $job->getData();
    $pheanstalk->delete($job);
}
```

So essentially, the producer puts a **job** onto the `choose_tube_name` tube / queue with a 3second delay. After 3seconds, it will be ready to consume by any consumers listening on the queue.

The consumer sits there waiting for a job, when one arrives, it reserves it, then echos the output, and deletes the job and because is in a while loop, it will wait till another job comes in to process.

In order to scale, you can have multiple **producers** and multiple **consumers**. One thing to remember however is that your consumer in example above is a long-running process. So watch for memory usage / leaks, and be careful in terms of sharing objects between jobs. e.g. if you instantiate a class outside of the while loop, and use / change it inside the while loop, then it's properties will creep into other jobs.

Comment: Finally I stoped on this decision. Your example works well. But I don't understand - how can I change variable in producer file from consumer file. May I pass variable by reference in put method? Or don't exist way to change variable in producer file from consumer? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @Log - If you want to create a PHP object and publish it to a producer, then  read and manipulate the object in a consumer, you will have to serialise it and deserialise it. I use `json_encode` / `json_decode`, but you could also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @Log - You could also take a look at: http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I use windows and Gearman is badly installed on it, I found another decision in the form of pthreads. I simply create new thread and put sleep(3).